# Need non-proleptic Gregorian chronology in Java 8 (like org.joda.time.chrono.GJChronology)

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time

I dont see the equivalent java.time.Chronology to org.joda.time.chrono.GJChronology.java, that is, a non-proleptic Gregorian Calendar ("the Gregorian/Julian calendar system which is the calendar system used in most of the world").

I know there is java.util.GregorianCalendar, but that doesnt implement java.time.Chronology. I need to allow user to specify the Chronology, so would be simplest to have a GregorianChronology class.

Is there some simple way to use GregorianCalendar to implement GregorianChronology? If its the "most used", why not include in java.time ??

Comment: Apologies, its joda.time.chrono.GJChronology.java, not joda.time.chrono.GregorianChronology.java,  that is what Im looking for. Its a mixed calendar, with Julian before some date, and Gregorian after. From that source file is this comment: "Implements the Gregorian/Julian calendar system which is the calendar system used in most of the world." Ive update the question to reflect that.

Comment: You can use the British version: [`BritishCutoverChronology`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/BritishCutoverChronology.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not included in the Java Runtime Library, but you can find e.g. a [Julian chronology](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/JulianChronology.html) in the [ThreeTen-Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

> ThreeTen-Extra provides additional date-time classes that complement those in Java SE 8.

Don't know where you found that "most used" quote. The javadoc of [`org.joda.time.Chronology`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Chronology.html) says:

> ISO - The **de facto world calendar system**, based on the ISO-8601 standard

The javadoc of [`org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/chrono/ISOChronology.html) says:

> Implements a chronology that follows the rules of the ISO8601 standard, which is **compatible with Gregorian for all modern dates**.

In Java 8+, [`java.time.chrono.IsoChronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/IsoChronology.html) is the default chronology used by most of the API.

Comment: So the answer I needed was  org.threeten.extra.chrono.BritishCutoverChronology, it has the functionality I need and works with java.time. thanks.